# iterate on array inside an object using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just recently posted a question. I was thinking of editing the question but I decided not to do it so that I don't confuse anyone. The difference is that the type for attributes is now a collection(an array).

```
{
  "attributes": [{
    "scott": {
      "fullname": "Scott D Man",
      "age": 48
    }
  }, {
    "bill": {
      "fullname": "William Shatner",
      "age": 45
    }
  }]
}
```

I still wanted to do the same output, show they key, fullname and age using ng-repeat.

Comment: Use ng-repeat = "attribute in attributes"  and then 
Object.keys(attribute)[0], Object.keys(attribute)[0].fullname and Object.keys(attribute)[0].age

Comment: I'm interested in your response since you only mentioned one ng-repeat. Right now, my code is using single ng-repeat and was hoping to not add another ng-repeat. Is it ok if you make a sample html? No need to create the controller as we already have the data above. I'm interested in seeing how the ng-repeat looks like using your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as below

```
  <div ng-repeat="attr in model.attributes">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in attr">
       Name: {{key}}
       Full Name: {{value.fullname}}
       Age: {{value.age}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's what I was planning to do earlier but I was hoping if we can do it by only using single ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

I was saying something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="attr in model.attributes">
{{getKeys(attr)}}
<div>{{attr[keys[0]]}}</div>
<div>{{attr[keys[0]].fullname}}</div>
<div>{{attr[keys[0]].age}}</div>
</div>
```

Here getKeys() function will be :

```
getKeys(attr){$scope.keys = Object.keys(attr);}
```

Still I would think to try putting data something like this :

{
  "attributes": [{
    "attribute" : "scott",
      "fullname": "Scott D Man",
      "age": 48
    }]
}

Comment: I can't change the data because it's our api team who structured it. Anyways, I got your idea.

Comment: Rather You can modify the data beforehand so that You don't clutter the view. Instead of doing getKeys after ng-repeat. Use a function modulateData() once you get data from API and then use it forever in your html with any hassle.

Comment: I actually did that so that my existing html template will be the same and it worked. :)